# How to pass log entry event to the appropriate Handler class?

Tags: php

I am learning how to write my own PHP logging class with handlers for writing logs to database, file, or print to screen.

My folder structure looks something like:

```
Logging
- Handlers
- - File.php
- - Database.php
- - Screen.php
- Logger.php
```

In my **Logger.php** class, I have the following so far:

```
class Logger {
    private $handler = null;

    public function error(string $message, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->logEvent($message, $context, 'Error');
    }

    public function handler($handler)
    {
         if (! $handler) {
              $handler = 'Screen';
         }

         $this->handler = $handler;
         return $this;
    }

    public function logEvent($message, $context, $level)
    {
        // Build the log entry into an array
        $entry = [
            'level' => $level,
            'message' => $message,
            'context' -> $context
        ];

        // Call the correct handler and provide the $entry
        

    }

}
```

For the file handler **File.php**

```
class File
{
    public function init()
    {
        $fp = fopen();
        ....
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

And my try/catch block looks something like:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->handler('File');
    $logger->error('Something bad happened.');
}
```

How do I trigger my code to use the File.php handler from Logger.php without having to run through multiple if/else statements for each handler?